# Where to get Ruby-opencv-0.0.10 API reference manual?

Tags: ruby, opencv

I cannot find Ruby-opencv 0.0.10 API manual on the web. On the web, I just find version 0.0.7 document, it seems out of date.

Then I try to create rdoc myself, but gem rdoc ruby-opencv cannot work.

```
gem rdoc ruby-opencv
Parsing documentation for ruby-opencv-0.0.10
unable to convert "\xE0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/opencv.so, skipping
```

How to solve it? Any suggestion is welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a way to get the API doc. It's quiet simple.
Just go to the source files dirctory of gem Ruby-opencv, then run rdoc there.
In myown machine, it's as following

```
cd /home/uncutstone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/ruby-opencv-0.0.10/ext
rdoc --ri
```